# Finding a point on a plane.

Tags: linear-algebra

So, I have a set of 3 points that form a triangle on the surface of a wall, from a depth camera.

[graph representation of wall](http://www.a.willruby.com/files/wall.png)

The camera is roughly where the green dot is, and the points correspond to the red points on this grid. The points are (in camera relative meters):

```
 C  -1.232, 0.596,  2.330
 L  -1.980, 1.086,  4.492
 R   0.328, 0.2,    2.905
```

I'd like to get the meter coordinates of the three blue points:

```
 1,  46
 1,  0
 84, 46
```

How can I go about this?

Just to give a little context, this grid corresponds to this:

[actual wall](http://a.willruby.com/files/IMG_0704.jpg)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok, I read the above alreay twice and I still have no pale idea what's being asked: what are meter coordinates? Measured from the origin of from the camera (which is, I think, already given)? Why are there three numbers by the right side of C,L,R is we're on a plane? ...

Comment: If you define the origin and reference frame of your points $C, L,$ and $R$, I should be able to help. Also if you could be a little more detailed in your problem statement that would help.

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry, meter coordinates meaning the units of those 3 coordinates is in meters. Relative the camera meaning that they're measured from that upper right position, at a crazy angle, pointed down at the wall.

The 3 points C, L and R are measurements taken from the depth camera which is mounted to one corner of the wall. 0,0,0 is the camera. 0,0,4 would be the limit of the camera's range, dead center. -1,0,4 is 1 meter left of center at the limit of the camera's range. 0,1,4 would be 1 meter up from center at the limit of the camera's range.

Comment: @Orangutango What I want is to convert the meter values from the camera to an X, Y pixel position on the surface of the wall. I have a program I've written that will create a transform matrix for me to do this if I have the upper left, upper right, and lower left position in meters, but I don't know how to make it work with arbitrary points on the same plane.

C, L and R are a plane in 3d space. They're called C, L and R, because one of those points is in the center of the wall, one is left of center, and one is right of center. They correspond to C 42,24 L 21, 0 and R 64, 0 in pixel space.

Comment: @Orangutango Its 0,0,0 in meter world space, so it'd be 82,50 in pixel space? To take a guess. I haven't measured from the wall to the sensor explicitly. I can though.

Comment: Can you edit the question to put the graph representation image inline and include the pixel coordinates for C,L,R in the body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the coordinates you report are rectilinear distances (as you implied in the comments). Then let $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ be the spacial vectors that represent one-pixel moves in the X and Y directions. Then you have
$$
\begin{align}
&R-L = 43\vec{x} \\
&C-L = 21\vec{x}+24\vec{y} \\
\vec{x} &= (R-L)/43 &= (0.0537,-0.0206,-0.0369) \\
\vec{y} &= (C-L-21\vec{x})/24 &= (-0.0158,-0.0024,-0.0578)
\end{align}
$$
from which you can get
$$
\begin{align}
1,46 &\to C-41\vec{x}+22\vec{y} &= (-3.780,1.388,2.572) \\
1,0 &\to C-41\vec{x}-24\vec{y} & = (-3.053,1.498,5.230) \\
84,46 &\to C+42\vec{x}+22\vec{y} & = (0.675,-0.322,-0.491)
\end{align}
$$

This should give you an idea of how to approach it, but I'm not sure these numbers make sense because from the way you describe it this puts $84,46$ behind the camera. Could there be distortion in the measurements of C,L,R?

Comment: Thank you, there's very likely noise, its a Kinect style sensor, and it's response once converted from camera space into meter's is far from continuous. It's certainly within the realm of possibility that it could be off, though by so far surprises me.

I'll attempt these coords in my mapper, and feed in the experimentally gained coords to that transform, and see how far off from the correct coords it is. But thanks again!

Comment: I was able to run the mapper this morning, and it seems like it gives reasonable results at each of the measured points, so I think any fault in the transform comes to inaccuracy at the sensor, not your math. Thanks again.